# Why is the same object throwing a "NoneType" object Attribute error in one instance and not others?

Tags: python, mysql, django, attributeerror, nonetype

I am using django to set up the cart functionality on my ecommerce site.  All items are entered as `cart_item`s in a MySQL table.

Before the question, the relevant code:

```
charm = False
if postdata.get('charm_sku'):
    charm_sku = postdata.get('charm_sku','')
    ch = get_object_or_404(Charm, sku=charm_sku)


#get products in cart
cart_products = get_cart_items(request)
product_in_cart = False
# check to see if item is already in cart
for cart_item in cart_products:
    if cart_item.product.id == p.id:
         if charm == True:
              if cart_item.charm.id == ch.id:
                 # update the quantity if found
                 cart_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
                 product_in_cart = True
         else:
             if cart_item.charm.id == "":
                # update the quantity if found
                cart_item.augment_quantity(quantity)
                product_in_cart = True
```

Edit: 
I reworked the code as shown above, causing BOTH `if cart_item.charm.id`'s to throw the attirbuteerror: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`.  In a way, I think this has improved the situation, since I suspect the first one seeming to "succeed" was in fact the first `if charm == True` failing, thus never testing the first `if cart_item.charm.id == ch.id`.  The question remains: why is this trowing the AttributeError, when the For loop is clearly declaring the cart_item, and cart_items clearly have both a charm column and id's assigned to said columns?

Edit 2:
Can I not reference cart_item from the nested if's?  That is the only thing I can think, but at the same time I feel like I should be able to, so maybe that is wrong?

Comment: Instead of `if x ==True: elif x == False:` it is preferred to use the idiom `if x: else:`.  If you MUST determine if they are exactly equal to `True` or `False`, you should use `if x is True: elif x is False:` This is because (for example) `0 == False` is true, but `0 is False` is false.

Comment: No, I have no reason, just a silly semantic error in prototype code. Will fix for production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NoneType` means that instead of an instance of a class, you've actually got `None`. That probably means that an assignment failed or or function call returned an unexpected result.  Your assignment to `cart_item` is probably failing in the case where `charm == False`.  Check whatever code (assignment or function call) that's setting those two variables.

Comment: I should've mentioned that the error is thrown on line 56, which is the line `if cart_item.charm.id == "":`.  Why would this line throw an error when `if cart_item.charm.id == ch.id:` does not? I have cut code from before and after the snippet provided, but nothing from the middle.  I'll add the declaration to the front of the snippet.

Comment: @fildred13 It appears to be the case that `cart_item.id` is assigned to an object when `charm == True`, but not when it's `False`.

Comment: I've expanded the code to include basically the entire `def add_to_cart`.  I understand that cart_item.id is assigned an object when `charm == True`, but I simply cannot see why it is not when it is false.  The assignment is occurring right there, just before the conditional test of `charm`, so is it something in the first conditional that is breaking the assignment?

Comment: Upon further tinkering, it should in fact have been `cart_item.charm_id` instead of `cart_item.charm.id`.  This answer more or less lead me down that path, since his reasoning was correct, I just had to figure out HOW the assignment was failing.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your `charm == False` condition also implies that `cart_item.charm is None`. Since you don't check for `None` before you access the `id` attribute, an exception is thrown.

I don't know enough about these variables and object types to understand why but it's that `if` conditional that's masking away your problem.